# What is the verb used with 'repentance' when the subject is God responding to someones repentance?

Tags: collocation

A person repents to God.

Then God responds to their prayer and (v) their repentance.

What verb goes here? What is the correct collocation?

The only examples I can find on the internet are :

'I was earnestly begging of God to **give** me repentance.'

and

'Then hath God also to the Gentiles **granted** repentance unto life.'

However, the meanings of these sentences are unclear. Does 'give/grant repentance mean that they were given the chance to repent?

That's not the meaning I'm looking for.

Comment: Repentance is not really a speech act; it happens either in Heaven (on which we have no data) or in one's imagination (ditto). Hence there is little likelihood that non-theological writers have a ready term for it. Theological writers, however, have hundreds of terms for it, and for everything else. You pays your attention and you takes your choice.

Comment: There is a verb in Arabic to describe the meaning I'm looking for: I need to translate it.

Comment: Based on the question raised in WS2's answer, perhaps God does not grant repentence, but he does hopefully *acknowledge* it.

Comment: @nicholasainsworth: what does your arabic-english dictionary say? What does google translate say?

Comment: "However, the meanings of these sentences are unclear. Does 'give/grant repentance mean that they were given the chance to repent?" Yes, those quotes are referring to the chance to repent; Chris' answer covers the main part of your question.

Comment: This realy seems **offtopic**. Most the answers are ultimately an opinion based on a specific concept of God and/or of repentance.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are just looking for *accepts,* "Then God responds to their prayer and **accepts** their repentance."

"Grants" or "gives" repentance both mean that God has *allowed* them to repent, in terms of God acting through them and changing their hearts.

Answer (score 5):

Does God 'grant repentance'? The position, as it seems to me, is that the individual repents and God grants ***forgiveness, absolution, remission of sins***, etc

Comment: Excellent point with your question.

Comment: The sentence with *granted* is verbatim new testament.

Comment: @δοῦλος The OED, under the verb *repent* lists various senses, however they all involve actions and conditions of the individual. None imply the idea of it being a state granted by God. Please can you give me the exact chapter and verse reference you mention from the New Testament, so we can try and get to the bottom of the matter.

Comment: @δοῦλος I assume you are referring to Acts Chapter 11 v 18, which in the KJV says: *When they heard these things, they held their peace, and glorified God, saying, Then hath God also to the Gentiles granted repentance unto life.* What I believe this means is that God has granted (in this case to the Gentiles) *the principle of repentance*, implying also *forgiveness* etc. That is slightly different to the idea that God 'grants repentance'.

Comment: Yes, *what you **believe** this means.* This is not based on language but upon presuppositions about God and about repentance, as are most answers here. Ultimately, these kind of answers express opinions. And I thought that questions that engender opinions are offtopic here. If it belongs aanywhere, maybe scripture interpretation.

Comment: @δοῦλος No it is ultimately a question of language we are discussing here. God has granted *the principle of repentance*, though under that principle the individual is required to repent. It is a bit like the government which has  granted a system of welfare benefits. But to avail oneself of them the individual (not the government) has to make application.

Comment: Define *God*. Define *repentance* in relation to *god*. The OP has not. Therefore anything may be answered.

Comment: @δοῦλος Now you are getting into the theological. I was only dealing with the language issue.

Comment: Don't "blame" me! It is inevitable. One uses language to express meaning. It is a fallacy to say one is dealing "only" with the language issue to answer such a question as this.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what God is doing with the offered repentance... Does he **accept** the repentance, as suggested above by Chris Sunami, or merely **hear** their repentance, or **cherish, acknowledge, reject, ignore, rejoice over, respond to, etc.**

Which word you choose to use is a question of language; which word you *should* choose is a question of theology.

Comment: Amen. I mean, frankly, yes. Your answer separates the realm of language from the realm of theology. Most other answers do not do this. Most other answers are informed by particular assumptions about God and about repentance. Ultimately, they are opinions. Which is why I say the question is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think God returns the repentance to the sinner so it can be reused.

Comment: @andy256 This answer provides as good an answer as most here. Most, including this one, are based on opinion. The question is off-topic, because it is not a question about language, but a question about beliefs. And that is the way almost every answer here is answering the question: with opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that genuine repentance, perhaps the only kind that a deity might want to consider, should be vetted and then "[confirmed](http://www.worldviewweekend.com/worldview-times/article.php?articleid=2313)" (or not) as such.

Answer (score 0):

God "Reciprocates to" repentance:
"Draw nigh to God and He will draw nigh to you..." James 4:8
Consider the story of the prodigal son in Luke 15:  The son repented, (came to his senses and headed home).  While he was still a long way off, his father saw him coming, and ran to him and kissed him and welcomed him home.  We're the prodigal, God is the father.

When a sinner repents, God doesn't just cooly "acknowledge" or stiffly "accept" it:  "Responds to" is close, but lacking the proper sense of God's enthusiams.  So I say He "reciprocates":  He runs to the sinner and welcomes him home.

Comment: Is God barefoot, wearing sandals, or cross-trainers?